# Google Play SMS and Calling Access

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm relatively new to Android, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I wrote a simple directory app to list out contacts of our organization.  Once you select a contact, you can click on one of two buttons: Call or Text.  When the Call button is pressed, it initiates a phone call to that person and when when the Text button is pressed, it initiates an SMS addressed to that person.  Here's my code:

```
private void makePhoneCall() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EntryDetailActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EntryDetailActivity.this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);

        } else {
            String dial = "tel:" + currentPhoneNumber;
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
        }

    }

    private void sendSMS() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(EntryDetailActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EntryDetailActivity.this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_SMS);

        } else {
            String dial = "sms:" + currentPhoneNumber;
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(dial)));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                makePhoneCall();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permission to make call!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SMS) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSMS();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permission to send text messages!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's what I have in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

After submitting to the Google Play store, am getting an email notification from Google stating:

Action required

Please read through the Permissions policy and the Play Console Help Center article, which describes intended uses, exceptions, invalid uses, and alternative options for use of Call Log or SMS permissions, to determine which of the following options apply to your affected app(s):

Option 1) Your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions: Remove the specified permissions from your app's manifest, or migrate to an alternative implementation by January 9, 2019. If you require additional time to remove permissions or migrate to an alternative option, submit a Permissions Declaration Form to request an extension until March 9, 2019.

Option 2) Your app is a default handler, or you believe your app qualifies for an exception: If you haven't already done so, submit a request using the Permissions Declaration Form by January 9, 2019. We are currently reviewing submissions and will respond to your request. Note: You do not need to make changes to your app in order to be eligible to submit a request.
Make sure that your app is otherwise compliant with all other Developer Program Policies to prevent your app from being removed.

We appreciate your continued support to make Google Play a positive experience for both developers and our users.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Google is no longer allowing apps with those permissions to be published in the Play Store, unless it is the app's main functionality. It's rather well explained right there, but they should've also linked you to a page with all of the info about the policy change, and what you can do to file an exemption request.

Comment: Note that you do not need the `SEND_SMS` permission for your code here, and if you switch to `ACTION_DIAL` instead of `ACTION_CALL` you could get rid of the `CALL_PHONE` permission as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you! So, just by switching to ACTION_DIAL, I can remove both permissions from AndroidManifest.xml and still have the app function properly?

Comment: @DavidB: Yes. `CALL_PHONE` is only needed for `ACTION_CALL` (directly placing a phone call). It is not needed for `ACTION_DIAL` (bringing up the dialer with a number pre-populated, so the user just has to press a "call" button to place the call). `SEND_SMS` is only needed if you are using `SmsManager` to directly send an SMS. Using `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` `Uri`, or hoping for the best with your `ACTION_VIEW`/`sms:` `Uri`, does not need that permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Right now, you are:

- Placing phone calls using `ACTION_CALL`, and
- Attempting to start an SMS client using `ACTION_VIEW` of an `sms:` `Uri`

Using an `Intent` to start an SMS client does not require the `SEND_SMS` permission. That permission is needed if you were using `SmsManager` to send an SMS directly. So, you could drop the `SEND_SMS` permission from your manifest and code to clear that up.

You do need the `CALL_PHONE` permission to use `ACTION_CALL` to directly place a phone call. If you were willing to use `ACTION_DIAL`, you could get rid of the `CALL_PHONE` permission. The cost is that `ACTION_DIAL` just brings up the dialer on your desired phone number, forcing the user to tap a button to place the call. I assume that is a reasonable trade-off here, as your SMS code does not actually send an SMS, but brings up an app that can send the SMS. Using `ACTION_DIAL` would bring parallelism to your actions, and it would allow you to eliminate both permissions.

Comment: I use smsManager. Why my app for sending sms is rejected?

Answer (score 0):

Google has marked `CALL_PHONE`,`SEND_SMS` etc as sensitive permission. As the contain personal data, it is not impossible for any one to misuse this data if not properly controlled or call/send message to any fishy number.

What they are trying to do is, Those app who are not primarily dependent on these permission, like a regular app who need sms verification or something similar, strip them off of these permission. And, only the apps whose core feature is dependent on those permission should have those permissions like Carrier app which use solely dependent on these permission, should have it.

Comment: hey , What if my app dont use sms and call log permission then what should i fill in my declaration form !??